# Why can't I display a let variable after changing it in a function?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently trying to assign different objects to a let variable using if statements before displaying it. For some reason, assigning the object in a function will result in the variable displaying nothing instead of displaying the assigned object.

Let me give an example:

In the following code I am assigning 2 different icons to a let variable depending on a prop I passed from another file and the result matches exactly what I'm looking for.

```
    const BottomBar = ({ screen }) => {
        let icon;

        if (screen === 'Home') {
            icon = (<Entypo name='home' size={30} color='white'/>);
        } else {
            icon = (<SimpleLineIcons name='home' size={24} color='white'/>);
        }

        return (
            <View>{icon}</View>
        );
    }
```

However, if I was to re-attempt this same example with a combination of a function with the useEffect hook, the {icon} object displays nothing.

```
    const BottomBar = ({ screen }) => {
        let icon;

        const checkScreen = () => {
            if (screen === 'Home') {
                icon = (<Entypo name='home' size={30} color='white'/>);
            } else {
                icon = (<SimpleLineIcons name='home' size={24} color='white'/>);
            }
        };

        useEffect(() => {
            checkScreen();
        });

        return (
            <View>{icon}</View>
        );
    }
```

Right away, I can assume this is because the function is asynchronous. The let variable "icon" is being used before assigning it with an object. So a simple fix would be something such as the following:

```
     const BottomBar = ({ screen }) => {
        const checkScreen = () => {
            if (screen === 'Home') {
                return (<Entypo name='home' size={30} color='white'/>);
            } else {
                return (<SimpleLineIcons name='home' size={24} color='white'/>);
            }
        };

        let icon = checkScreen();

        return (
            <View>{icon}</View>
        );
    }
```

But what if I want to re-assign the variable icon with a different object later on after a button is pressed. Simply assigning an object right away doesn't allow me to re-assign it later. What I would like to do is assign the object as needed. What am I missing? Am I passing the variable wrong or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The let variable doesn't make the page rerender after the assignment so the value is changed but the react component doesn't read it, use the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook instead for purposes like this, but I advise you to use conditional rendering for your case like this:

```
const BottomBar = ({ screen }) => {
    const checkScreen = () => {
        if (screen === 'Home') {
            return (<Entypo name='home' size={30} color='white' />);
        } else {
            return (<SimpleLineIcons name='home' size={24} color='white' />);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View>{checkScreen()}</View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I like your example as it does solve this specific issue. But what if I wanted to re-assign multiple variables at once in the same function using the same if statement, thereby preventing me from being able to use the return statement. You mentioned using the useState, how would I use it for objects?

Comment: const [someObj, setSomeObj] = React.useState({name:'alex', age:69});

//Change the object
const changeAge = ()=>{
        someObj.age = 420;
        setSomeObj(someObj);
}

Comment: This simply sets a variable named 'someObj' with basic values like strings and integers. I need to use it for objects like the icon or maybe an image.

Comment: As I said above, use conditional rendering for situations like these.